# TextView doesn't show the text

Tags: android, textview

Sorry for this such long pot but I need help here. I am new to Android World and follows the book "Android Development" by Chris Stewart (The Big Nerd Ranch). All goes well but now I got stuck. When I run my application, it crashes with this line of code

```
String text = Integer.toString(question);
```

According to book, it shows me the Question Text. I changed my code to this as well but it show me 0.

```
String text = Integer.toString(Integer.toString(question));
```

Any solution for this. Thanks in Advance.
Here is my complete code.

QuizActivity.java

```
package com.example.subrose.geoquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans,true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
     mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);

    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);

    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Question.java

```
public class Question {

private int mTextResId;
private boolean mAnswerTrue;

public Question(int mTextResId, boolean mAnswerTrue)
{
    mTextResId = mTextResId;
    mAnswerTrue = mAnswerTrue;
}

public int getTextResId() {
    return mTextResId;
}

public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
    mTextResId = textResId;
}

public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
    return mAnswerTrue;
}

public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
    mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
}

}
```

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
<string name="true_button">True</string>
<string name="false_button">False</string>
<string name="next_button">Next</string>
<string name="correct_toast">Correct!</string>
<string name="incorrect_toast">Incorrect!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="question_oceans">The Pacific Ocean is larger than the Atlantic Ocean.</string>
<string name="question_mideast">The Suez Canal connects the Red Sea and the Indian Ocean.</string>
<string name="question_africa">The source of the Nile River is in Egypt.</string>
<string name="question_americas">The Amazon River is the longest river in the Americas.</string>
<string name="question_asia">Lake Baikal is the world\'s oldest and deepest freshwater lake.</string>
</resources>
```

activity_quiz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: instead of mQuestionTextView.setText(question); please use mQuestionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(question));

Comment: Or please use mQuestionTextView.setText(""+question);

Comment: Where did you use `Integer.toString(question)` in code . I can not see it .

Comment: Again tried it. I still shows 0.

Comment: Shanto George, tried ""+question as well, it still shows me 0.

Comment: I used Integer.toString(question) in multiple runs. I post here an actual code that was in book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your constructor . Change it as  below.

```
public Question(int mTextResId, boolean mAnswerTrue)
 {
   this.mTextResId = mTextResId;
    this.mAnswerTrue = mAnswerTrue;
 }
```

You should use `this` in data shadowing . Currently value is not assigned to instance variable cause you just used local ones. That's why they are returning the default value.  Do it as above .

Apart from that `setText()` has several variant if you are using a resource id the you can directly use `setText(int id)`. Read [setText varients](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) .

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me in. I still don't believe this how I forgot to use "this" variable in Constructor.
Well now it works with this

mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

Once again Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

you can't set integer in settext so change code from

`mQuestionTextView.setText(question);`  to replace with

```
mQuestionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(question));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();

mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
```

to set integer in TextView you have below possibilities :

replace it with:

```
mQuestionTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", question));
```

or

```
mQuestionTextView.setText(question+"");
```

or

```
mQuestionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(question));
```

Comment: Hi Dhiren, Tried all possibilites suggested by you. It still shows me 0.

Comment: because your integer variable question value becomes 0, so textview print 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check using:

```
mQuestionTextView.setText(getString(mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId()));
```

Anyway, I didn't see any error in your Code to set the text in your View.

Comment: Did you check that your getTextResId is returning a value?